# Is the function $f(x) = 1/x$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

A function f is mapped from the non-zero reals to the reals . We assume the natural topology to be induced on the domain. Then is the function f(x) = 1/x continuous ?

**EDIT** Suppose I use this definition of continuity :
         The inverse image of any open set in the co-domain is an open set in the domain.
         Then what could I say about the inverse image of, let's say (-1,1) ?

Comment: Bz natural topology, do you mean the topology induced by the metric?

Comment: Yes, the one induced by the Euclidean Metric.

Comment: the function $x\to \frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Isn't it an elementary calculus question?

Comment: It can be proved the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of continuity is equivalent to its topological definition. Not so hard.

Comment: That's okay - But the problem that I'm facing is specifically this - if I choose an open set in the co-domain such that it contains a point which has no inverse image in the domain - can it still be said that its inverse image is an open set ?

Comment: Ok, I understand now. It doesn't matter if a specific point in an open set Im choosing has an inverse image or not - it follows from the definition of inverse image of a set actually.

Comment: If point $y$ in the co-domain has no inverse image in the domain, then the inverse image of $\{y\}$ is just the empty set $-$ which is open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer concerning your edit.

In full terms the preimage of $\left(-1,1\right)$ under function $f:\mathbb{R}\backslash\left\{ 0\right\} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
prescribed by $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$, is set $\left(-\infty,-1\right)\cup\left(1,\infty\right)$.
This is evidently an open subset of $\mathbb{R}\backslash\left\{ 0\right\} $.

It can be shown that $f^{-1}\left(U\right)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}\backslash\left\{ 0\right\} $ if $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ which means that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

For the topology, induced by a metric, a function $f$ is continuous if for every $x$ and every $\epsilon$, there exists such a $\delta $ that for all $y$, $d(x,y)<\delta$ implies $d(f(x)-f(y))<\epsilon$.

This is the standard definition of continuity known from mathematical analysis. Using tools  from analysis, it is not hard to show that $f$ is, indeed, continuous.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can say for $x,y>1$ you have
$$
\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right|=\left|\frac{x-y}{xy}\right|\leqslant|x-y|
$$
The general case follows by symmetry, since $1/x$ is its inverse.